# PHP run jar file on Ubuntu

Tags: java, php, linux, jar, executable-jar

Consider this code:

```
<?php
$output=shell_exec('ls');
shell_exec('java -jar gimtadieniai2.jar');
echo $output;
?>
```

The line with 'ls' simply tests to see if it works, and it does.

The goal is to execute java with the "gimtadieniai2.jar". When executed manually from terminal, it works. Note that the jar file picks information from one file and puts it into other file.

My problem is that PHP code not working. Any ideas why?

Comment: What is the error thrown? capture it and post it ..

Comment: No error, like i said wen i run "java -jar gimtadieniai2.jar" from terminal it words and creates .txt file. But when in Php nothing happens. Part where "ls" is working and i get list for files and foldes, but no created new txt file.

Comment: is the code being executed in the correct directory/filepath?

Comment: did't notice that you're capturing the output of 'ls', not the output of jar execution. What happend if you change the code in $output = shell_exec('java -jar gimtadieniai2.jar');?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if no error is thrown.

If all was well, then `Main` class in the executable `jar` must be returning no output and doing a safe exit. If it is not so, but returns some output, then use `echo shell_exec(....` and see if there is any difference.

Other possible reason I think is `classpath` available for `java`.
`jar` file might be in the same folder as `php` file.
But `java` is not able to load the `jar` from the same path of `php`.
You better input an *absolute file path* of `jar` file. This may resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

What about the path? Is the jar file in the same folder of the php script? If so, try `shell_exec('java -jar ./gimtadieniai2.jar');`